# DOMDocument type object recognition

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

This is my php code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html ='<html><body><input type="text" name="test" id="test" class="form-control" value="120.00" style="text-align: right;"></body></html>';
$dom->loadHTML($html);      
$myElement = $dom->getElementById("test");
```

How to get the type of object  and type with property (input type="hidden")?  for example

```
if ($myElement->is('input')) then etc....
if ($myElement->is('img')) then etc....
if (($myElement->is('input')) && ($myElement->has('hidden'))) then etc....
```

is possible?
Thank's a lot.
Aesis.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this... Make use of the [`getAttribute`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) of the [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) Class

```
    <?php
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $html ='<html><body><input type="text" name="test" id="test" class="form-control" value="120.00" style="text-align: right;"></body></html>';
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('input') as $tag) {
        if ($tag->getAttribute('name') === 'test') {
        echo $tag->getAttribute('value'); //"prints" 120.00
        echo $tag->getAttribute('type'); //"prints" text (attribute)
      }
    }
```

You can do the same for other attributes too.

Comment: Thank's a lot. Works!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try $myElement->tagName or $dom->getElementById("test")->tagName ?

http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/domdocument.getelementbyid.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
You can get the type of object by using the code below..

```
$typeofObj = $myElement->nodeName;
echo $typeOfObj;
```

and to find it has attribute "hidden" then

```
$node = $dom->saveHTML($myElement);
if(preg_match("/(hidden)/i",$node)) {
    // has hidden
}
else { //not have hidden
    }
```